# Champions League Structure Algorithm - how to?

Tags: php, algorithm

I am trying to understand an issue that arose following the news regarding the new format of the Champions League.

As some of you may know, the new format consists of `n=36` teams, divided into `p=4` pots. Each team will face `o=2` teams from each pot, resulting in a total of `p*o=8` matches, with one match played away and one at home for each pot.

### Update

This is my attempt as now. For low values of N_TEAMS the script works in a reasonable time, for larger it can stuck. It surely need some optimization, what can I optimize?

PS:the biggest issue is the limitation on the number of matches to be played home vs away (if that control is removed, everything is really fast!)

```
<?php

const N_TEAMS   = 36;
const N_POTS    = 4;
const M_PER_POT = 2;
function main()
{
    $teams    = array_map(fn($i) => "team_{$i}", range(1, N_TEAMS));


    foreach($teams as $team) {
        $teams_pots[$team] = findPotOfTeam($team, $teams, N_POTS);
    }

    foreach(getPossiblePots(N_TEAMS) as $pot) {
        echo "Can be divided in {$pot} pots - with these number of matches per pot" . json_encode(getPossibleMatchesNumberPerPot(N_TEAMS, $pot)) . "\n";
    }

    if(!in_array(N_POTS, getPossiblePots(N_TEAMS))) {
        throw new Error('POTS NUMBER IS WRONG');
    }

    if(!in_array(M_PER_POT, getPossibleMatchesNumberPerPot(N_TEAMS, N_POTS))) {
        throw new Error('MATCHES PER POT WRONG!');
    }
    $schedule = generateSchedule($teams, getFixture($teams, $teams_pots), $teams_pots);

    // Calendar
    foreach ($schedule as $day => $matches) {
        echo "\nDay " . ($day + 1) . ":\n";

        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            echo implode(" vs ", $match) . "\n";
        }
    }
    $flat     = array_merge(...$schedule);


    foreach($teams as $team) {
        $matches_home = count(array_filter($flat, fn($t) => $t[0] == $team));
        $matches_away = count(array_filter($flat, fn($t) => $t[1] == $team));
        echo "\n{$team} plays " . $matches_home + $matches_away . " matches: {$matches_home} H - {$matches_away} A\n" ;

        for($i = 0;$i < N_POTS;$i++) {
            $home_pots = count(homeTeamMatchesVSPot($team, $flat, $i, $teams_pots));
            $away_pots = count(awayTeamMatchesVSPot($team, $flat, $i, $teams_pots));
            echo  "POT {$i}: H " . $home_pots . " A:" . $away_pots . "\n";
        }
    }

}

function getPossiblePots(int $nTeams): array
{
    return array_filter(range(1, $nTeams), fn($e) => ($nTeams % $e == 0 && $e != $nTeams));
}
function getPossibleMatchesNumberPerPot(int $nTeams, int $pots): array
{
    return  array_values(array_filter(range(1, $nTeams / $pots - 1), fn($e) => (($nTeams / $pots % 2 == 0) || ($e % 2 == 0))));
}

function findPotOfTeam($team, array $teams, int $nPots): int
{
    $pots_length = ceil(N_TEAMS / $nPots);
    $pos         = array_search($team, $teams);

    return ceil(($pos + 1) / $pots_length) - 1;
}

function getFixture(array $teams, array $teams_pots)
{

    $chunked_teams = array_chunk($teams, N_TEAMS / N_POTS);

    /* Opponents array initialization */
    foreach($teams as $team) {
        $teams_opponents[$team] = [];
    }

    foreach($teams as $team) {
        /* Skip team if opponents filled */
        if(count($teams_opponents[$team]) == N_POTS * M_PER_POT) {
            continue;
        }

        /* Check each pot for $team*/
        for($pot = 0;$pot < N_POTS;$pot++) {
            $opp_of_teams_in_pot = opponentsOfTeamOfPot($teams_opponents[$team], $pot, $teams_pots);

            /* If team has M_PER_POT opponents in POT, skip */
            if(count($opp_of_teams_in_pot) == M_PER_POT) {
                continue;
            }

            /* If team has more than M_PER_POT opponents in POT, restart */
            if(count($opp_of_teams_in_pot) > M_PER_POT) {
                return  getFixture($teams, $teams_pots);
            }
            /*
            Team here has less opponents in POT than M_PER_POT,
            so we will find, among the teams in pot, the possible opponents.
            */
            $remaining_opponents = array_filter(
                $chunked_teams[$pot],
                fn($val) => (
                    $val != $team
                        && !in_array($val, $teams_opponents[$team]) // all teams that are not already paired
                        && (count($teams_opponents[$val]) < (N_POTS * M_PER_POT)) // all teams that have space left for team
                        && (count(opponentsOfTeamOfPot($teams_opponents[$val], $teams_pots[$team], $teams_pots)) < M_PER_POT)// all teams that have space left for team in pot
                ),
            );

            /* If there are no opponents left, restart */
            if(count($remaining_opponents) == 0) {
                return getFixture($teams, $teams_pots);
            }
            /* We can pick, from this pot, an amount of random opponents that is the minimum between the num of opponents left and the opponents left in pot */
            $opponents           = array_rand(array_flip($remaining_opponents), min(count($remaining_opponents), M_PER_POT - count($opp_of_teams_in_pot)));

            /* If one element is picked we turn it into array */
            if(!is_array($opponents)) {
                $opponents = [$opponents];
            }

            /* We add each opponent to the list of opponents of $team, and to each $opponent we add $team as opponent */
            foreach($opponents as $o) {
                $teams_opponents[$team][] = $o;
                $teams_opponents[$o][]    = $team;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Double check */
    foreach($teams as $team) {
        if(count($teams_opponents[$team]) != N_POTS * M_PER_POT) {
            return getFixture($teams, $teams_pots);
        }
    }

    return $teams_opponents;
}


function opponentsOfTeamOfPot(array $team_opponents, int $currentPot, array $teams_pots)
{
    return array_values(array_filter($team_opponents, fn($t) => $teams_pots[$t] == $currentPot));
}


function matchesOfTeam($team, array $plays): array
{
    return array_values(array_filter($plays, fn($play) => in_array($team, $play)));
}
function matchesOfTeamAgainstPot($team, array $plays, int $pot, array $teams_pots): array
{
    return array_values(array_filter(matchesOfTeam($team, $plays), fn($play) => ($teams_pots[$play[0] == $team ? $play[1] : $play[0]] == $pot)));
}
function homeTeamMatchesVSPot($team, array $plays, int $pot, array $teams_pots): array
{
    return array_values(array_filter(matchesOfTeamAgainstPot($team, $plays, $pot, $teams_pots), fn($play) => $play[0] == $team));
}
function awayTeamMatchesVSPot($team, array $plays, int  $pot, array $teams_pots): array
{
    return array_values(array_filter(matchesOfTeamAgainstPot($team, $plays, $pot, $teams_pots), fn($play) => $play[1] == $team));
}

function getNumberOfMatchesPerTeam($team, $plays)
{
    return count(array_values(array_filter($plays, fn($play) => in_array($team, $play))));
}
function getNumberOfMatchesPerTeamHome($team, $plays)
{
    return count(array_values(array_filter($plays, fn($play) => $play[0] == $team)));
}
function getNumberOfMatchesPerTeamAway($team, $plays)
{
    return count(array_values(array_filter($plays, fn($play) => $play[1] == $team)));
}

function generateDay(array $teams, array &$teams_opponents, array $teams_pots, $matches_for_team_home, $matches_for_team_away, $matches_for_team_home_pot, $matches_for_team_away_pot, array $last_home)
{
    $day            = [];

    $remainingTeams = array_filter($teams, fn($team) => ($matches_for_team_home[$team] + $matches_for_team_away[$team]) != N_POTS * M_PER_POT);
    /* We order the remaining teams first on the total matches, then on the home matches and then on the away matches. Always ASC */
    usort($remainingTeams, function($a, $b) use ($matches_for_team_home, $matches_for_team_away, $last_home) {
        $matchesTotalComparison = ($matches_for_team_home[$a] + $matches_for_team_away[$a]) - ($matches_for_team_home[$b] + $matches_for_team_away[$b]);

        if ($matchesTotalComparison != 0) {
            return $matchesTotalComparison;
        }
        $last_home_order        = $last_home[$a]                                            - $last_home[$b];

        if($last_home_order != 0) {
            return $last_home[$a] - $last_home[$b];
        }

        $matchesHomeComparison  = $matches_for_team_home[$a]                                - $matches_for_team_home[$b];
        $matchesAwayComparison  = $matches_for_team_away[$a]                                - $matches_for_team_away[$b];

        if ($matchesHomeComparison != 0) {
            return $matchesHomeComparison;
        }

        if($matchesAwayComparison != 0) {
            return $matchesAwayComparison;
        }

        /* Seems to fix some infinite loop in some cases... you figure it why... */
        return rand(-1, 1);

    });

    while(count($remainingTeams) > 0) {
        // Let's pick the first team
        $team1  = array_shift($remainingTeams);
        $team2  = null;
        /* We order opponents with the same method of before */
        usort($teams_opponents[$team1], function($a, $b) use ($matches_for_team_home, $matches_for_team_away, $last_home) {


            $matchesTotalComparison = ($matches_for_team_home[$a] + $matches_for_team_away[$a]) - ($matches_for_team_home[$b] + $matches_for_team_away[$b]);

            if ($matchesTotalComparison != 0) {
                return $matchesTotalComparison;
            }

            $last_home_order        = $last_home[$b]                                            - $last_home[$a];

            if($last_home_order != 0) {
                return $last_home[$b] - $last_home[$a];
            }
            $matchesAwayComparison  = $matches_for_team_away[$a]                                - $matches_for_team_away[$b];
            $matchesHomeComparison  = $matches_for_team_home[$a]                                - $matches_for_team_home[$b];

            if ($matchesAwayComparison != 0) {
                return $matchesAwayComparison;
            }

            if($matchesHomeComparison != 0) {
                return $matchesHomeComparison;
            }

            return rand(-1, 1);
        });
        $couple = [];

        foreach($teams_opponents[$team1] as $potOpp) {
            /* Is the possible opponent yet to be coupled in the day?*/
            if(!in_array($potOpp, $remainingTeams)) {
                continue;
            }
            $team2         = $potOpp;
            /* Now we check which team should play home and which away */
            $t1_H_VS_P_T2  = $matches_for_team_home_pot[$team1][$teams_pots[$team2]];
            $t2_H_VS_P_T1  = $matches_for_team_home_pot[$team2][$teams_pots[$team1]];
            $t1_A_VS_P_T2  = $matches_for_team_away_pot[$team1][$teams_pots[$team2]];
            $t2_A_VS_P_T1  = $matches_for_team_away_pot[$team2][$teams_pots[$team1]];
            $t1_stop_H_PT2 = $t1_H_VS_P_T2 >= ceil(M_PER_POT / 2);
            $t2_stop_H_PT1 = $t2_H_VS_P_T1 >= ceil(M_PER_POT / 2);
            $t1_stop_A_PT2 = $t1_A_VS_P_T2 >= ceil(M_PER_POT / 2);
            $t2_stop_A_PT1 = $t2_A_VS_P_T1 >= ceil(M_PER_POT / 2);

            if($t2_stop_H_PT1 && $t2_stop_A_PT1) {
                $team2 = null;

                break;
            }

            $couple        = [$team1, $team2];

            if($t1_stop_H_PT2 || $t2_stop_A_PT1) {
                /*
                If team1 has already enough matches against the pot of team 2 as HOME
                OR
                If team2 has already enough matches against the pot of team 1 as AWAY
                Team 2 will play home and Team 1 will play away
                 */
                $couple = [$team2, $team1];

                if($t2_stop_H_PT1 || $t1_stop_A_PT2) {
                    /*
                If team 2 has already enough matches against the pot of team 1 as HOME
                OR
                If team 1 has already enough matches against the pot of team 2 as AWAY
                we have to break as the schedule is not right
                 */
                    $team2 = null;

                    break;
                }
            }

            break;
        }

        if ($team2) {
            /* We add the match to the day and remove team_1 from the opponents of team_2 and vice-versa. */
            $day[]                   = $couple;
            $teams_opponents[$team1] = array_diff($teams_opponents[$team1], [$team2]);
            $teams_opponents[$team2] = array_diff($teams_opponents[$team2], [$team1]);
            $remainingTeams          = array_diff($remainingTeams, [$team1, $team2]);
        }
    }

    return $day;
}

function generateSchedule($teams, $teams_opponents, $teams_pots, &$iteration = 0)
{
    $schedule         = [];
    $completedMatches = [];

    $initial_team_opp = $teams_opponents;
    $total_matches    = array_reduce($teams_opponents, fn($carry, $opp) => $carry + count($opp), 0) / 2;

    if($iteration > 5) {
        $iteration = 0;

        return generateSchedule($teams, getFixture($teams, $teams_pots), $teams_pots, $iteration);
    }
    echo "\nTotal matches: " . $total_matches . "\n";

    foreach($teams as $team) {
        $matches_for_team_home_pot[$team] = array_map(fn() => 0, range(0, N_POTS - 1));
        $matches_for_team_away_pot[$team] = array_map(fn() => 0, range(0, N_POTS - 1));
        $matches_for_team_home[$team]     = 0;
        $matches_for_team_away[$team]     = 0;
        $last_home[$team]                 = true;
    }

    /* Loop to run until the number of completed matches is not equal to the total needed */
    while (count($completedMatches) < $total_matches) {

        $day              = generateDay($teams, $initial_team_opp, $teams_pots, $matches_for_team_home, $matches_for_team_away, $matches_for_team_home_pot, $matches_for_team_away_pot, $last_home);

        if (empty($day)) {
            break;
        }
        $schedule[]       = $day;
        $completedMatches = array_merge($completedMatches, $day);

        foreach($teams as $team) {
            $matches_for_team_home_pot[$team] = array_map(fn($pot) => count(homeTeamMatchesVSPot($team, $completedMatches, $pot, $teams_pots)), range(0, N_POTS - 1));
            $matches_for_team_away_pot[$team] = array_map(fn($pot) => count(awayTeamMatchesVSPot($team, $completedMatches, $pot, $teams_pots)), range(0, N_POTS - 1));
            $matches_for_team_home[$team]     = getNumberOfMatchesPerTeamHome($team, $completedMatches);
            $matches_for_team_away[$team]     = getNumberOfMatchesPerTeamAway($team, $completedMatches);

            $last_home[$team]                 = array_search($team, array_merge(...$day)) % 2 == 0;

        }

    }

    if(count($completedMatches) != $total_matches) {
        $iteration++;

        return generateSchedule($teams, $teams_opponents, $teams_pots, iteration:$iteration);
    }

    foreach($teams as $team) {
        if(abs($matches_for_team_home[$team] - $matches_for_team_away[$team]) > 1) {
            $iteration++;

            return generateSchedule(
                $teams,
                $teams_opponents,
                $teams_pots,
                iteration:$iteration,
            );
        }
    }

    return $schedule;
}

main();
```

For limited number of total matches it works, but for the champions league structure it gives infinite loop error. How can I make it faster/correct?

Comment: Please clarify your question, I'm not certain what the "next step" is that you are having problems with. It would also be useful for you to include some output from your code and compare that with what you expect to see.

Comment: Hi sorry if I wasnt clear. Please check the edit, thanks!